# How do I Mockito-test that methods are called in logically correct order without UnnecessaryStubbingExceptions?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

My Java REST handler receives an ID and should read and return the corresponding entity. However, it should do so only in case the caller is authorized to access the endpoint:

```
MyEntity getEntity(String id) {
    authorityChecker.assertHasReadAuthorization(); // throws AccessDeniedException if not
    var myEntity = entityReader.readMyEntity(id);
    return mapAndAddTransientFields(myEntity;
}
```

If the read happened before the authorization check, it would reveal sensitive information that the caller has no access to.

For example, if there is no entity with ID "1234", the unauthorized caller should get HTTP 403 Unauthorized. If the read happened before, they might get HTTP 404 Not Found instead, revealing that there is no such entity.

I'd therefore like to safeguard that the two things happen in the logically correct order. So I thought I'd write a unit test like this:

```
doThrow(new AccessDeniedException()).when(authorityChecker).assertHasReadAuthorization();
when(entityReader.readMyEntity("1234").thenThrow(new EntityReadException());

assertThrows(AccessDeniedException.class, () -> cut.getEntity("1234"));
```

In case the method would perform the read before the authorization check, it would get the wrong exception type, and the unit test assert would fail.

However, Mockito rejects this with an UnnecessaryStubbingException, saying that the `entityReader.readMyEntity` is not validated and should be removed.

I could switch to "lenient" mode which accepts this kind of overstubbing, but I am generally happy with the strict settings and would like to retain these.

I could also hard-wire the expected method call order into the unit test, but this sounds like over-tight coupling and I'd like to avoid that.

Is there a way to redesign the test I have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Mockito can also verify there were no interactions with a mock.  Adding to your code snippet, verify that when there is an `AccessDeniedException` the read did **not** happen:

```
 @Test
 void getEntityShouldNotAttemptToReadWhenAccessIsDenied() {
     ...
     assertThrows(AccessDeniedException.class, () -> cut.getEntity("1234"));
     verifyNoInteractions(entityReader);
 }
```

That line that creates the `UnnecessaryStubbingException`can just be removed since

```
var myEntity = entityReader.readMyEntity(id)
```

should never be reached.  And as you said, if for some reason the `AccessDeniedException` is not thrown, the test will already fail as expected.